# Reset Entire Web Page To Original State

Tags: javascript, image

I have written some javascript that enlivens otherwise boring webpages by replacing all embedded images with better images of Marty Feldman. However, in order to mitigate the obliteration of functionality this usually causes, I would like to have the webpage reset back to its original state after a few seconds. What is my best bet?

My first thought was to save `document.body.innerHTML` in the variable `savedPage` and set a timer to set `document.body.innerHTML=savedPage`, but this seems to throw off some events; no dynamically loaded images will load after this happens, and one page (Citizen's Bank login) grays out and displays a permanent "Please Wait" gif (probably some weird security measure).

I am also genuinely curious if there is a way to make this work.

Comment: If all you're doing is replacing images, select and store all img elements with their original src in an array. Do your marty feldman stuff, then use that array to repopulate the imgs with their original src.

Comment: @EricGuan: Thanks, this does work better than anything I'd tried so far. Although there are still a few weird bugs: If you mouse over the preview pictures on a Craigslist ad before the page resets, the images you've moused over will load in really low-res for some reason; thumbnails lower down on the front page of Youtube stay gray... I think there probably isn't a perfect way to do this, though. Which is strange to me; I would've thought a simple way to reset a page would've been provided for in the spec at some point.